# Second bounded cohomology and normal subgroups

Tags: group-cohomology, geometric-group-theory

It may be a naive question, but:

> If a finitely generated group has an infinite-dimensional second bounded cohomology group, does it imply that it contains "many" normal subgroups?

But "many", typically I have in mind "infinitely many" or even "uncountably many".

I am not familiar with bounded cohomology, but several articles deduce that the second bounded cohomology group is "big" from suitable actions on Gromov-hyperbolic spaces, where similar (but stronger) conditions can be used to construct normal subgroups via small cancellation. So I am wondering if there exists a connection between having a big second bounded cohomology and having many normal subgroups. For instance, can a simple group have an infinite-dimensional second bounded cohomology group?

Comment: Infinite-dimensional second bounded cohomology means that you have infinitely many quasi-morphisms to the reals. One may argue that the kernel of such a quasi-morphism should be a quasi-normal quasi-subgroup, whatever that means :-)

Comment: My vague recollection from reading Monod's book many years ago is that _vanishing_ $H^2_b$ (for trivial coefficients) is the exception rather than the rule; and my intuition from the cohomology of Banach algebras (which in some sense subsumes $H^*_b$ for discrete groups) is that once the 2nd cohomology group is non-zero it is usually infinite-dimensional. Therefore I am tempted to guess that the answer to your last question is "yes", on the basis that there are no obvious obstructions. However, none of this constitutes a possible proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question.

> **Proposition:** There exists a finitely presented simple group whose second bounded cohomology group is infinite-dimensional.

Such an example comes from the study of Kac-Moody groups. The simplicity of such groups is studied in Caprace and Rémy's article [Simplicity and superrigidity of twin building lattices](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607664). On the other hand, Caprace and Fujiwara, in their article [Rank one isometries of buildings and quasi-morphisms of Kac-Moody groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.0470), showed that many Kac-Moody groups act on a building with rank-one isometries, and, following a previous work of Bestvina and Fujiwara, they constructed "many" quasi-morphisms, proving that $\widetilde{QH}$ is infinite-dimensional. As $\widetilde{QH}$ naturally lives inside $H_b^2$, the desired conclusion follows.

As an interesting consequence, it follows that such Kac-Moody groups are simple but not uniformly perfect (and so, not uniformly simple).